# In visual studio 2010 how can you debug a class

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

When I set a breakpoint in a class then access a method, debugger does not hit breakpoint. What would be best way to debug a class?

Comment: Is it failing for even a simple test program, or just for your particular class?

Comment: What type of application is this? WebApp, Console, WPF, etc?

Comment: Run it as debug, don't just run it as an application, for a start.

Comment: Is the class you're trying to debug part of the the same solution as the application using it?

Comment: Does not fail in a simple test.
It is a WebApp, think this is why not working with debugger
I do run in debug mode.
class is part of solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Maybe your code doesn't reach the breakpoint.
- Maybe your compiled code wasn't compiled from the source that you have opened.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to post the method. My 1st thought is to make sure you're compiling in Debug mode, not release.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that you have compiled your solution in debug mode (select Debug as your solution configuration). Then make sure that you are running in debug mode (press F5 or from the menu select Debug|Start Debugging).
If the above have been done then set the breakpoint earlier in the method that is being called. Can't be more specific without seeing your code.